# If earlier the SIM card is used in multiple mobile device; can we find or trace those mobile's imei numbers?

Tags: user-tracking

Can we trace the imei numbers of mobile devices in which SIM card was used previously, & if it was used in multiple mobile devices?

Comment: Do you only have access to the SIM card, or can you access the telco's connection logs as well?

Comment: As Graham Hill commented above, if you have access to telco's logs it would be possible. Your requirement seems to be very unusual though.